# Flask-User : Impossible to install flask-user I get an permission error

Tags: python, flask, pycryptodome

Hi I 'm trying to install flask-user its seems that it don't want to be installed 
I used a virtualenv environment and python3.7 flask 1.1.2 
I have looking for how to fixe it but I didn't find any solutions , is it someone can help me to fix that,  I put you the traceback below

```
     (env) C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto>pip install "Flask-User<0.7"
    Collecting Flask-User<0.7
      Downloading Flask-User-0.6.21.tar.gz (64 kB)
         |████████████████████████████████| 64 kB 141 kB/s
    Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (3.1.7)
    Requirement already satisfied: Flask in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (1.1.2)
    Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Login in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (0.5.0)
    Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Mail in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (0.9.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: Flask-SQLAlchemy in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (2.4.1)
    Requirement already satisfied: Flask-WTF in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (0.14.3)
    Requirement already satisfied: passlib in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (1.7.2)
    Collecting pycryptodome
      Downloading pycryptodome-3.9.7-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (14.1 MB)
         |███████████████████████████▌    | 12.1 MB 234 kB/s eta 0:00:09ERROR: Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 425, in _error_catcher
        yield
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 507, in read
        data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
        data = self.__fp.read(amt)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\http\client.py", line 457, in read
        n = self.readinto(b)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\http\client.py", line 501, in readinto
        n = self.fp.readinto(b)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\socket.py", line 589, in readinto
        return self._sock.recv_into(b)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\ssl.py", line 1071, in recv_into
        return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\ssl.py", line 929, in read
        return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
    socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 186, in _main
        status = self.run(options, args)
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 331, in run
        resolver.resolve(requirement_set)
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 177, in resolve
        discovered_reqs.extend(self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req))
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 333, in _resolve_one
        abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\legacy_resolve.py", line 282, in _get_abstract_dist_for
        abstract_dist = self.preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(req)
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 482, in prepare_linked_requirement
        hashes=hashes,
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 287, in unpack_url
        hashes=hashes,
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 159, in unpack_http_url
        link, downloader, temp_dir.path, hashes
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 303, in _download_http_url
        for chunk in download.chunks:
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\ui.py", line 160, in iter
        for x in it:
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 39, in response_chunks
        decode_content=False,
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 564, in stream
        data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 529, in read
        raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)
      File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\contextlib.py", line 130, in __exit__
        self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
      File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 430, in _error_catcher
        raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
    pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.
```

I firstly got this error but I tried to fix that with using --default-timeout and another error appeared that have blocked me to continue my projet I put another traceback below

```
    (env) C:\Users\hp\Travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto>pip install --default-timeout=100 "Flask-User<0.7"
Collecting Flask-User<0.7
  Using cached Flask-User-0.6.21.tar.gz (64 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: bcrypt in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (3.1.7)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Login in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Mail in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (0.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-SQLAlchemy in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (2.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-WTF in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (0.14.3)
Requirement already satisfied: passlib in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-User<0.7) (1.7.2)
Collecting pycryptodome
  Downloading pycryptodome-3.9.7-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (14.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 14.1 MB 172 kB/s
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.1 in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from bcrypt->Flask-User<0.7) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.4.1 in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from bcrypt->Flask-User<0.7) (1.14.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask->Flask-User<0.7) (2.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask->Flask-User<0.7) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask->Flask-User<0.7) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask->Flask-User<0.7) (7.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: blinker in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-Mail->Flask-User<0.7) (1.4)
Requirement already satisfied: SQLAlchemy>=0.8.0 in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-SQLAlchemy->Flask-User<0.7) (1.3.16)
Requirement already satisfied: WTForms in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Flask-WTF->Flask-User<0.7) (2.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.1->bcrypt->Flask-User<0.7) (2.20)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask->Flask-User<0.7) (1.1.1)
Installing collected packages: pycryptodome, Flask-User
  Attempting uninstall: Flask-User
    Found existing installation: Flask-User 1.0.2.2
    Uninstalling Flask-User-1.0.2.2:
      Successfully uninstalled Flask-User-1.0.2.2
    Running setup.py install for Flask-User ... done
Successfully installed Flask-User-0.6.21 pycryptodome-3.9.7
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 450, in run
    wheel_cache.cleanup()
  File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.cleanup()
  File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\temp_dir.py", line 175, in cleanup
    rmtree(self._path)
  File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrapped_f
    return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
  File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in call
    raise attempt.get()
  File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get
    six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
  File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\six.py", line 703, in reraise
    raise value
  File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in call
    attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
  File "c:\users\hp\travaux\flask-projet\flask_user_tuto\env\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\misc.py", line 136, in rmtree
    onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\shutil.py", line 516, in rmtree
    return _rmtree_unsafe(path, onerror)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\shutil.py", line 395, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\shutil.py", line 395, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\shutil.py", line 395, in _rmtree_unsafe
    _rmtree_unsafe(fullname, onerror)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\shutil.py", line 400, in _rmtree_unsafe
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\lib\shutil.py", line 398, in _rmtree_unsafe
    os.unlink(fullname)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Accès refusé: 'C:\\Users\\hp\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-m96_7wsd\\pycryptodome\\Crypto\\Cipher\\_ARC4.cp37-win_amd64.pyd'
```

I hope someone can help to fix that thank you

Comment: Run cmd as Administrator and try again.

Comment: @Devansh Soni It seems that it works now thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try run as administrator.

Good luck.

Comment: "Trying" is not an answer, but a suggestion, a comment